# How to run my laravel project on vps?

Tags: laravel, vps, digital-ocean

Now I just finished my laravel web application and want to upload to vps (digital ocean).In local, i usually trying to use by typing php artisan serve ,then go to access http://localhost:8000/ ,and everything is fine. But on vps ubuntu, how to type to run my laravel application,I already upload my project to git and pull from vps. I follow [this](https://gist.github.com/santoshachari/87bf77baeb45a65eb83b553aceb135a3) instruction,but this instruction is just installation.Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need vcs or ftp (not recommended). Also, read about nginx (default in DO) or apache and try to configure it local for beginning

Comment: Since you are using Digital Ocean you must be having SSH Access to the Server then you can try [this link](https://github.com/akshaykhale1992/nginx-php-mysql-setup) to setup NGinx, Mysql, PHP, Composer and Git on your server after that you can simply clone the repository and run `composer install` and create necessary directories and directory permissions, it will work.

Comment: i have done all the process bro, since i installed those tutorial and got the laravel home page and then ,if i change to routes like Route::get ( '/hello', function () {
    return view ( 'welcome' );
} ); insetead of get('/'), its show 404 error not found @AkshayKhale

Comment: if you remove `Route::get('/')` route then on homepage you will surely get 404 Error. @ThanHtutOo

Comment: so it means that, my ipaddress(http://***.***.***/bla) is not working? @AkshayKhale

Comment: did you properly configured the NGinx refer [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) for better reference... `server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}` @ThanHtutOo

Comment: Here is a post with more complete informations: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-prod-server

Comment: its work now @rap-2-h thanks